# Illustrated book from the 1980s or 1990s with paintings of possible lifeforms on Venus, Jupiter, etc

Tags: story-identification

I had this book as a kid with beautiful paintings of different lifeforms that could inhabit the planets in our solar system. Venus has large black creatures with giant ears. Jupiter has floating gasbags. Europa has creatures with ice-skate-like appendages for feet. I've Googled a bit, but I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This sounds like the hypothetical lifeforms in the National Geographic *Our Universe* book, except that the creatures with the big ears are from Mars, not Venus:

Jovian Jellyblimp:

[image: Jovian Jellyblimp]

Europan Brinker-roo:

[image: Europan Brinker-roo]

Martian Waterseeker:

[image: Martian Waterseeker]

The cover of *Our Universe*:

[image: Cover of "Our Universe"]

Comment: The skating creature on Europa is pretty distinct, so I'm reasonably confident about this.

Comment: That's it! I found that book in my search, but the spaceship on the cover threw me off. I didn't remember any spaceships. But the images of the creatures are exactly as I remember.

Comment: *National Geographic* did this?  Don't they usually concern themselves strictly with non-fiction?  Seems weird to see them delving into pure sci-fi like this...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman, Most of the book was about what we knew at the time, but they had a brief section about hypothetical lifeforms. I think the purposes of that section were to get people excited about the search for extraterrestrial life and to illustrate just how different each world is from Earth. The book also contained illustrations of the mythological figures associated with each planet. (Venus, Pluto, Jupiter, etc)

Comment: Wow! My dad had this as one of our "coffee table" books when I was a younger kid and I always thought it was so amazing. What an awesome memory to be reminded of, thanks! I still think the cover of the book has some of the cooler spaceships I've seen.

Comment: IIRC they did speculate about Venusian creatures;  they were shown snacking on a *Venera* probe or something like that.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert That's correct: Venus had "Oucher-pouchers" who bounced around and ate metals and ores.  (Titan had "Stovebellies" who ate oxygen ice and burned it in the methane atmosphere to keep warm, and Pluto had crystalline "Zistles.")

Comment: @KyleA I have no conscious memory of the actual factual stuff. The fantastical lifeforms were much more memorable apparently.

Comment: Neat! Does that book make any mention of silicon-based lifeforms? I recall a biology textbook I used in high school with a really cool picture of a marine worm-like creature and this answer got me wondering if that image was borrowed from this very book.

Comment: I was thinking of this myself earlier this year, how I'd read the book over and over as a kid, and this chapter in particular.  I ordered a used copy online, and it seems to be a different edition, from the late 1980's, as it does not have this chapter.  But the rest of the book is the same as I remember, including the cover.

Comment: I love that the rocket-plume coming out of the spaceship is (a) apparently **fire** like what you see in the fireplace, and apparently there is an **up** for the flames of this fire that corresponds to the orientation of the shaceship which is also independent of the nearby planet's gravity well.

Comment: This was my first thought also. I actually have this book. It was a Christmas gift from my grandparents back in the 80s maybe? Way back... Loved this book. Read it a million times... The book I got was in a box that also came with a star wheel and a 45 record of "star sounds" or something like that. I found the box, the book, and the star wheel but I don't know where the record is. Good memories...